# Python Selenium - 'dict' object is not callable - click on a list of elements

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, element

I'm using Selenium Webdriver. I try to make a loop in order to :
* click on one element of a list of elements 
* go back to the homepage

The "typical" Source code of the webpage for each edition of the newspaper is that one :

```
<div id="tuile-52a774ce495870b16070a4a72f62ce55d2d0768e5dd8f19ed5a99" class="media media-multi-col wow fadeIn  well article-list-item" data-id-revue="CHIME" date-id-numero="CHIME_094" data-id-article="" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeIn;"><div class="media-left">
                                <a href="revue-chimeres-2019-1.htm"><img class="media-object img-thumbnail" src="/vign_rev/CHIME/CHIME_094_L61.jpg"></a>
                          </div><div class="media-body"><div class="media-body-inner-wrapper"><div class="article-meta"><ul><li class="titre-numero"><a href="revue-chimeres-2019-1.htm"><b>Avec Danielle Sivadon</b></a></li><li class="reference">2019/1 (N°&nbsp;94)</li></ul></div><div class="article-toolbox"><a class="" href="./connexion.php?from=ajoutBiblio&amp;id=CHIME_094&amp;type=biblio" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Ajouter à ma bibliographie">
                        <span class="icon icon-biblio-add"></span>
                        <span class="name"></span>
                   </a></div></div></div><div class="media-footer">
                            <div class="article-action"></div>
                      </div></div>
```

My code is that one :

```
articles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("titre-numero")
NumArticles = len(articles)

for num in range(1,NumArticles) :
    time.sleep(0.8)
    articles[num].location_once_scrolled_into_view(False)
    if articles[num].is_displayed() :
        articles[num].click()
        driver.back()
```

But when I try to run it, I have this error message : 'dict' object is not callable. I don't know what to do to solve this problem.

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location_once_scrolled_into_view` is a ***property*** & ***returns dict*** of X, Y coordinates, but you're calling it,

```
location_once_scrolled_into_view(False)
```

That is why the error is `'dict' object is not callable`

Must read - Selenium python [API Documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I tried that because I saw that it would center my element on my screen - a rolling bar on the top of the screen is blocking my click -, but I was obviously wrong. Thank you again.